# Tax Exemption on Foreign Currency Income in India

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, foreign-income

If a salaried person in India also makes 20,000 USD (in the entire financial year) from affiliate marketing and freelancing with US clients, would those 20,000 USD have any tax exemption in India?

That 20,000 USD is transferred to Indian Bank Savings Account via TransferWise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tax exemption. You have to declare it as income from other sources and pay taxes as per tax brackets